# update select option element with Ajax result

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i have two select option list with values retrieved from db .

```
<select id="userid" onchange="selSuj()">
<option value="1" selected="selected">text1</option>
<option value="2">text2</option>
<option value="3">text3</option>
</select>

<select id="subject">
<div id="determineSubj">
<option value="1" selected="selected">text1</option>
<option value="2">text2</option>
<option value="3">text3</option>
</div>
</select>

<script>
function selSuj(){
   var x = $('#userid').val();
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'same page url',
      data:{
        'userid':x
      },
      success: function(result){
      document.getElementById("determineSubj").innerHTML = result;
      }
   })
   ;
}
```

the first select option(userid),when option selected, should populate the corresponding values in the second select option(subject), using the user option value(eg 1,2,3) as search p.key to the subject db.
I have tried using ajax, it worked out well on alert(result), but does not update the second select option values. please help.

Comment: Why is there a `div` inside your `select` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `select` should not contain a `<div>`.

As we can see from this brief demo, doing so makes the div inaccessible to JavaScript, because it doesn't consider it to be a valid part of the DOM:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("determineSubj"));
});
```

```html
<select id="subject">
  <div id="determineSubj">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
  </div>
</select>
```

In any case, even if it was valid, it's entirely unnecessary for your purpose. You can just update the HTML of the `select` element directly.

Change the HTML to:

```
<select id="subject">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
```

And the "success" callback to:

```
success: function(result) {
  document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = result;
}
```

and there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: wow ...i didnt even realize i should be updating my select element Id, rather i was messing around with the option id ..thanks again ADyson. coding isnt easy atall